# Synonimize [tax] to [taxes]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

I just asked a question and noticed there were two tax-related tage: [tax](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax) and [taxes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes). There was no usage guide and there were only 10 uses of [tax], so I went and retagged those. Some actually used both, which doesn't help anything. So I'd like to ask that [tax] be synonimized into [taxes].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. Enjoy the automated synonmym creation